# Как при нажатии кнопки "Обменять BTC на USDT" или "Обменять USDT на BTC" перейти к оплате, подгружая интерфейс биржи, не выходя из телеграмма?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
@CryptoBot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def btc(message):
    if message.text == "Обменять BTC на USDT":
        CryptoBot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Введите количество BTC которое желаете обменять на USDT:")
        value = message.text
        CryptoBot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f"{value} = ")
        if value:
            check = requests.get(f"https://waves.exchange/#send/8LQW8f7P5d5PZM7GtZEBgaqRPGSzS3DfPuiXrURJ4AJS?recipient=3P8u5JynYRcxEhdTbvrF4DnRnwSe4WBVvaw&amount={value}&strict")
            print(check)
        else:
            CryptoBot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Ошибка")
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.